# Need help removing li bullets in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am creating a ul in Javascript and despite my efforts I cannot seem to remove the bullets from the list items.  I have the following javascript:

```
var btnUL = document.createElement("ul");
btnUL.id = "btnUL";
btnUL.style.listStyleType = "none";
document.getElementById("leftGutter").appendChild(btnUL);
document.getElementById("btnUL").style.listStyle = "none";
```

and I have tried to add css for #btnUL on my style sheet for the list-Style-Type with no luck.  What am I doing wrong here??  I placed both attempts at changing the style type in the javascript to demonstrate that I have tried those approaches.  I have tried them both separately as well.

Comment: Is there any css rule interfering with your changes because your script works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/5gLwbdvr/

Comment: by all accounts, this looks like it should work -- could you post a jsfiddle or something so we can see it not working?

Comment: No css rules, and I tried adding  list-style-type: none; to the div the ul is being added to with no luck.  I will try adding a JS fiddle, but I have never used it before, so we'll see how that goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can only be 1 reason why your list still has bullets. And that is a css rule using `!important`to force a list-style-type. That also explains why you couldn't remove the bullets by using a css rule.

First fiddle is the same code which you are already using. And it works fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/5gLwbdvr/

Second fiddle has a certain css rule to force the bullets:

```
ul { list-style-type:disc !important }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5gLwbdvr/1/

If that is not the reason then there must be a problem in the way you are populating the list.

//Edit: After seeing how you populate the list:

You need to append the list items to the list and not to the container.

```
document.getElementById("btnUL").appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
```

Comment: I am never using !important in my code.  Here is how I am adding list items: var btnArray = [btnNCAL, btnSCAL, btnROC, btnDAP, btnEMIAtools];
    for (i = 0; i < btnArray.length; i++)
    {
        var l = document.getElementById("leftGutter").appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
        l.setAttribute("id", i);
        document.getElementById(i).appendChild(btnArray[i]);
    }